# Display trace and debug messages from the docker logs console for ASP.NET Core apps

Tags: docker, logging, asp.net-core

I have a [fairly standard ASP.NET MVC App](https://github.com/justaprogrammer/JustAProgrammer.AspNetCore.Auth.SslProxy) that I am serving through the basic Linux docker image. It happens to have a separate ssl reverse proxy, but that's irrevelant to this issue.

I have logging in Appsettings.Development.json set like this:

```
"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": true,
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Trace",
    "System": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Information",
    "JustAProgrammer.AspNetCore.Auth.SslProxy.Extensions": "Trace",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Trace",
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel": "Trace"
  }
}
```

I have trace and debug messages all over my code. They show up in the debug console in Visual studio. However, if I just do a `docker-compose run` or a `docker-compose logs` I only see `info` and `warn` messages. Is there another place I need to set logging preferences on Linux docker images?

Comment: What is your `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` set to in Docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set a env var `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`

Second, use following configuration in `appSettings.Developement.json`:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong, it just started working. I do know its not necessary to do `Copy Always`, so I removed that from your answer.